# Trying to run node.js server for some reason it's not accepting my code

Tags: node.js, json, npm

I was watching a tutorial to run node.js server and I did the same exact thing that he was doing but it's not working.

**Here is the package.json:**

```
   {   
      "name": "myserver",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "form",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts":{
        "start":"node index.js",
        "myserver":"nodemon index.js",
        "newtailor":"npm start --prefix newtailor",
        "dev":"concurrently \"npm run myserver\" \"npm run newtailor\""},
        "author": "wes",
        "license": "ISC",
        "dependencies": 
       {"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
         "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
         "cors": "^2.8.5",
         "express": "^4.17.1",
         "nodemailer": "^6.4.17",
         "nodemon": "^2.0.6"}
    }
```

**It's giving this error.**

```
npm ERR! JSON.parse "newtailor":"npm...'
npm ERR! JSON. parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

Comment: What command did you run?

Comment: I took this `package.json` and it works ok

Comment: npm run dev and  npm start

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen before when running an older Node version.

As far as I remember `npm cache clean` helped.

This is a valid package.json file. I tested it here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

```
{
   "name":"myserver",
   "version":"1.0.0",
   "description":"form",
   "main":"index.js",
   "scripts":{
      "start":"node index.js",
      "myserver":"nodemon index.js",
      "newtailor":"npm start --prefix newtailor",
      "dev":"concurrently \"npm run myserver\" \"npm run newtailor\""
   },
   "author":"wes",
   "license":"ISC",
   "dependencies":{
      "body-parser":"^1.19.0",
      "concurrently":"^5.3.0",
      "cors":"^2.8.5",
      "express":"^4.17.1",
      "nodemailer":"^6.4.17",
      "nodemon":"^2.0.6"
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I did npm cache clean still not working.

Comment: Weird. I tried running the package.json and it didn't output any parsing errors. Only that I don't have anything installed and files are missing. What OS are you using and what npm version?

Comment: I am using Windows10.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you try to create a blank project, do npm init -y, add in all dependencies and only then add scripts.

Comment: I did create a blank project when I run it gives me this error.  npm ERR! missing script: start.  Then I plugged in everything it's still the same.

Comment: Ok, missing script is a different error. Try removing newtailor and dev scripts. See which ones cause the error.